# Remove parent and sub directory

Tags: rm

```
sample_dir2
`-- sample_dir
    |-- cambridge
    |   `-- security
    |       |-- annex
    |       `-- parking
    |-- history.exe
    |-- markham
    |   |-- annex
    |   |-- building1
    |   `-- parking
    `-- stenton
        |-- admin
        |   `-- accounting
        |       `-- payroll
        |-- gen_ed
        |   `-- Holidays
        `-- lib_arts
            `-- english.txt
```

Your current directory is stenton. Remove the accounting directory:

You entered: `rm -r /admin/accounting`
Please try again.

Your current directory is stenton. Remove the accounting directory:

Shouldn't `rm -rf /admin/accounting` work?

Comment: Not unless stenton is also the system's root, but almost definitely `/` is.

Comment: This is ULI101 at Seneca College, which we get year after year.  [All assignments **"MUST consist of the student’s OWN work"**.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211656/copying-and-relative-home#comment358558_211656)

Answer (score 7):

Paths that start with `/` are from the root of the entire filesystem.  Leave off the slash to specify a file relative to the current directory.  You can also say `./admin/accounting` to refer to a path relative to `.`, which is the current directory.

Comment: Leaving off the slash worked, thank i did not know that it would specify it to the Current directory.